# Get all the multiple transactions on the last date of each account in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

Any help is appreciated. I have a table with fields "SalesmanID", "TransDate", "Brand", "Quantity" and "Total". What I want to get is **all** the transactions of a particular salesman for the **last** date.
Sample:

```
|Transaction Date | SalesmanID | Brand | Quantity | Total |
  6/3/2015               101      LE123      2       1000
  6/3/2015               101      GO123      1       500
```

I have this code but what it does is give me **all** the transactions of a salesman including the previous dates.

```
 SELECT MAX(TransDate) AS [Transaction Date], Brand, Quantity, Total
 FROM DailySalesReport
 WHERE SalesmanID = ?
 GROUP BY Brand, Quantity, Total
```

Sample:

```
|Transaction Date | SalesmanID | Brand | Quantity | Total |
  6/3/2015               101     LE123      2       1000
  6/3/2015               101     GO123      1       500
  6/2/2015               101     MN12       5       2000
```

I need all the transactions of 1 salesman on the last date.
Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the max transaction date in the where clause.

```
SELECT TransDate AS [Transaction Date], Brand, Quantity, Total
FROM DailySalesReport
WHERE SalesmanID = ? AND TransDate = (
    SELECT MAX(TransDate)
    FROM DailySalesReport
    WHERE SalesmanID = ?)
```

Comment: Sweet and Simple. Thanks.